# global variable for regex in django url

Tags: django, url

There's a particular regular expression I use multiple times in url.py.

Is there a way of defining a global parameter and using it instead of rewriting the same regular expression?

For example, instead of:

```
url(r'^blog/$', 'blog.views.page'),
url(r'^blog/page(?P<num>(option1|option2|option3|option4).*)/$', 'views.page'),
url(r'^blog/comment(?P<num>(option1|option2|option3|option4).*)/$', 'views.comment'),
url(r'^blog/user(?P<num>(option1|option2|option3|option4).*)/$', 'views.user'),
```

this:

```
myregex = "(option1|option2|option3|option4)"

url(r'^blog/$', 'blog.views.page'),
url(r'^blog/page(?P<num>myregex.*)/$', 'views.page'),
url(r'^blog/comment(?P<num>myregex.*)/$', 'views.comment'),
url(r'^blog/user(?P<num>myregex.*)/$', 'views.user'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are just strings. The `r'...'` syntax indicates *raw strings* (i.e. it only means that no escaping and quoting constructs will be recognized within the string), it is not specific to regular expressions. You can compose strings in many ways:

```
myregex = r'(option1|option2|option3|option4)'

url(r'^blog/$', 'blog.views.page'),
url(r'^blog/page(?P<num>' + myregex + r'.*)/$', 'views.page'),
url(r'^blog/comment(?P<num>%s.*)/$' % myregex, 'views.comment'),
url(r'^blog/user(?P<num>{options}.*)/$'.format(options=myregex), 'views.user'),
```